# Displaying alert dialog only after a specific activity page

Tags: android, dialog

I have a login page.When the user logs in correctly,I want to show an alert dialog saying that your login details have been verified.Click continue to proceed.Now I want this alert dialog to be shown on the next activity page after login.
Here is the alert dialog code-:

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
         boolean dialogShown = settings.getBoolean("dialogShown", false);

```
     if (!dialogShown) {
           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(Myperwallet.this);
           builder.setTitle("Fast Cashier!");
           builder.setMessage("Logging In");
           builder.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   dialog.cancel();
       //continue activity here....

               }
           });  

           builder.create().show();
             // AlertDialog code here


     }



       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
       editor.putBoolean("dialogShown", true);
       editor.commit();
```

I tried this but now alert dialog won't display after I have logged out.I need to know how can I set the flag to true when I have pressed the logout button.Here is my logout button functionality-:

```
 logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
              public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Myperwallet.this).create(); 
                alertDialog.setTitle("FastCashier:");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");
                alertDialog.setButton( Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                       Intent logout = new Intent(Myperwallet.this,Login.class);
                       startActivity(logout);

                   }
                   });

                alertDialog.setButton( Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()    {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                      dialog.cancel();

                  }
                  });

                alertDialog.show();  
              }
            });
```

Comment: You need to write code again for that in the second Activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some implementation to your current code.
You can keep a flag in sharedPrefs and initially it would be true. After showing it for first time make it false.
This is what you must have implemented right now.

So to show it again after logout reset the flag to true when user has logged out. So again when u reach to the activity the dialog would be shown.

Comment: Hey Sweety can u tell me how can i reset the flag?See my edited code above.

Answer (score 0):

actually could not get Under stood more issue, but you want show your `AlertDialog` in some `Optionnale` `Requirement` such as when `Login` then it show and in next page is `Required` but due to `SharedPreferences`  displayed only once at the start of the application. When I logged out and then logged in I did not get any `alert dialog`

`SharedPreferences`  what do do is store  your specific Sting with key and you need to match with it. after loing suceessufully you need to `Update`  `SharedPreferences` with some new String and need to match with it.

also You can use `File` to check `isExit()` or not and write require Sting it and Read it and match with you require condition to show `alert dialog`. this may Helps you.

Answer (score 0):

keep track of the activity flow ,i.e when u start your application it is doing what so ever is in onCreate method ,for ur problem set flag in the on create method ,and when u switch from any other activity to this one implement the method on Restart() and clear ur previous data ....
like this...

```
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();

    //ur code
}
```

hope it will be helpful,